# updating html/css/java files on a server with a .htm extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am updating and redesigning an old website, currently using html 4.01 to html 5. The site has decent search engine rankings and they want to protect this. The redesign consists of fairly simple static pages. I have never updated a live website before, but have a decent grasp of html, css, java and jquery. My first question is is it better to preserve the .htm file extension for the pages that the website currently uses, or redirect them to a new page with a different file extension? Secondly, to update the pages, is it as easy as copying and pasting the new html code into the html page files already on the server, and uploading the new css and java files? Or should I be using a program to do this?

Thank you all!

Comment: Have a local copy of the site - obviously you don't want to be working directly on the live site. Some sort of version control system is definitely beneficial. Make your changes, test them, then FTP them up to the live site :)

Comment: From what you've said, I don't see why you'd need to do anything other than copy the files from one server to the other and then update them as you see fit.  Also, it's not Java - it's Javascript (I changed the question tag).  They're *very* different things.

Comment: You should start by trying and see what happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My first question is is it better to preserve the .htm file extension for the pages that the website currently uses, or redirect them to a new page with a different file extension?

Keeping the same URL is preferred over an HTTP (or any other client side) redirect.

The file name doesn't have to particularly relate to the URL though.

> to update the pages, is it as easy as copying and pasting the new html code into the html page files already on the server

It depends on how the site currently operates. If it only uses static files, then yes, but you'd probably be better off doing the changes on a development system and then publishing them using a tool like rsync.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is, maintain the filename of all the files, have a local copy, edit the local copies not forgetting to change the `<!doctype html>` to reflect html 5 and push to the live server. but dont forget, have a copy of the live server before overwriting, use [git](http://git-scm.com/) if you want a reliable source code management and versioning system

Comment: You are welcome, if you think it is helpful why not vote it as answer or vote the answer up.

Answer (score 0):

Never work/edit on the live site directly. First, make a backup, archive it, and set up a development environment where you will work. (Consider using revision control too.) Also set up a test server (where your client can check the site before it goes live). And if everything is tested and okay you can deploy the site on the live server.

> My first question is is it better to preserve the .htm file extension
>   for the pages that the website currently uses, or redirect them to a
>   new page with a different file extension?

If you want to change the URL structure and keep the "seo ranks" you should use proper 301 redirects.

> If you need to change the URL of a page as it is shown in search
>   engine results, we recommend that you use a server-side 301 redirect.
>   This is the best way to ensure that users and search engines are
>   directed to the correct page. The 301 status code means that a page
>   has permanently moved to a new location.

Read more here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for the help. The client wants to keep the current URL structure with the addition of new pages.